# Is public transport running from Ushuaia to Tierra del Fuego National Park?

Tags: public-transport, argentina

Pre-pandemic, public transport ran between the town of Ushuaia, and Tierra del Fuego National Park.

Ushuaia Integral SE appears to service the town with a few bus routes, confirmed by the [municipality of Ushuaia](https://www.ushuaia.gob.ar/recorrido-colectivos), but I can't find anything on public transport to destinations further out, like the National Park.

Who knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I visited Ushuaia last week.

There is no public transport between the town and the national park.

However, there are private shuttles that run between the central bus station and the national park, as well as a few other destinations.

Tickets are sold at a desk at the central bus station. They leave at three times in the morning, come back at three times in the afternoon. They can drop you off and pick you up from a few places in the park. The cost for a round trip is the equivalent of around 15 euros.

Comment: This is broadly consistent with my recollection of how transit along this route worked in 2019, before covid, as well. Maybe there were a few more departures but I don't think there was like a municipal bus or something.

Comment: This is still correct as of Jan 2024, except that the buses theoretically run about once an hour.